# Why did Kai believe that Oogway betrayed him in Kung Fu Panda 3?

Tags: plot-explanation, kung-fu-panda-3

In Kung Fu Panda 3, when we learn the history between Kai and Oogway, we see that they used to be brother in arms and when the later was seriously injured, Kai took him to the secret Panda village where the Pandas taught Oogway how to give chi. Kai wanted the power for himself and they fought, Oogway won and banished Kai in the spirit realm.

But later into the movie, Kai says that it was Oogway that betrayed him. Why did Kai say that? Did Oogway actually betray him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when Kai was trying to Destroy the Pandas & the panda village, Oogway took the side of Pandas to protect them. Oogway took the right side. So, while kai was like a Brother to Oogway, the latter chose to fight Against Kai even he Helps Oogway So much. That's why kai said to betray you betrayed me.